# UWP, Content Dialog for Login

Tags: c#, authentication, dialog, uwp

How to use Content Dialog as simple Login screen.
When I try to use it like this:

```
ContentDialog d = new ContentDialog();
        d.Content = contentGrid;
        d.PrimaryButtonText = "aaa";
        d.PrimaryButtonClick += async delegate
        {

        };
await dlg.ShowAsync();
```

On button click I can run some logic, but it does hide EntireDialog. I want to show some processing animation, and show some "Check" results. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is possible. The key point here is using [ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs.GetDeferral method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialogbuttonclickeventargs.getdeferral.aspx) to get a [ContentDialogButtonClickDeferral](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialogbuttonclickdeferral.aspx) before you performe async operations and then complete the deferral when the async operation is complete. For example:

```
ContentDialog contentDialog = new ContentDialog();
contentDialog.Content = "Login Test";
contentDialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Login";
contentDialog.PrimaryButtonClick += async (s, args) =>
{
    ContentDialogButtonClickDeferral deferral = args.GetDeferral();

    //Do Some Async Sign In Operation
    await Task.Delay(3000);  //Here I just wait 3 seconds

    deferral.Complete();
};
await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
```

And there is an example shows how to create and use a custom dialog (**SignInContentDialog**) derived from `ContentDialog` under the **Examples** section in [ContentDialog class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx). You can have a check.

Comment: I got issue, when I use incorect Login, and then push Cancel button, entire window closes. =\

Comment: @J.Duck This is intentional, when user click Cancel button, the ContentDialog will be closed.